# Loomann-Menchoff Theorem Proof

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{U} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and $f=u+\dot \iota v : \mathbb{U} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. If the partial derivatives $u_{x},u_{y},v_{x},v_{y}$ exist and satisfy Cauchy Riemann equations at every point $a \in \mathbb{U}$ then f is holomorphic.

My attempt :

Partially differentiating $f=u+\dot \iota v$ with respect to x and y obtains

$f_x= u_{x}+ \dot \iota v_{x}$
and $f_y= u_{y}+ \dot \iota v_{y}$

Since $f_{x}(a,b)$ exists iff $u_x(a,b)$ exists, similarly for $f_y(a,b)$.

Construct a matrix $A$ as,

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
u_{x}(a) & u_{y}(a)\\
v_{x}(a) & v_{y}(a)
\end{pmatrix}$

Let $T :\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be the linear transformation corresponding to the matrix $A$.

The set $\{(1,0),(0,\dot \iota)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Then for any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}$,

$\begin{align}(x,y) & = x(1,0)+y(0,\dot \iota) \\
\implies T(x,y) & = xT(1,0)+yT(0,\dot \iota)\\
\implies T(x,y) & = x(u_x(a),v_x(a)+y(u_y(a),v_y(a))\\
\implies T(x,y) & = xf_x(a)+yf_y(a)\\
\implies T(x,y) & = (x+\dot \iota y)f_{x}(a)\end{align}$

Using Cauchy Riemann equations to show that the matrix $A$ has the form

$\begin{pmatrix} Re(f) & Im(f)\\
-Im(f) & Re(f)\end{pmatrix}$

The linear map $T :\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{C}$- linear.

Now,
$\begin{align}\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(a+z)-f(a)}{z}\end{align}$

$\begin{align} 
& = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{u(x'+x,y'+y)+ \dot \iota v(x'+x,y'+y)- u(x',y')- \dot \iota v(x',y')} {x+ \dot \iota y}\\
& = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{u(x'+x,y'+y)-u(x',y')} {x+ \dot \iota y} + \dot \iota \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{v(x'+x,y'+y)-v(x',y')}{x+ \dot \iota y}\\
& = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{u(x'+x,y'+y)-u(x'+x,y')}{x+ \dot \iota y} +\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{u(x'+x,y')-u(x',y')}{x+ \dot \iota y} + \dot \iota \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{v(x'+x,y'+y)-v(x'+x,y')}{x+ \dot \iota y}+ \dot \iota \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{v(x'+x,y')-v(x',y')}{x+ \dot \iota y} \\
& = \lim_{{x\to 0},{y=0}} \frac{u(x'+x,y')-u(x'+x,y')}{x} +\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{u(x'+x,y')-u(x',y')}{x+ \dot \iota y} + \dot \iota \lim_{{x\to 0},{y=0}} \frac{v(x'+x,y')-v(x'+x,y')}{x+ \dot \iota y}+ \dot \iota \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{v(x'+x,y')-v(x',y')}{x+ \dot \iota y}\\
& = 0+u_{x}(a)+0+\dot \iota v_{x}(a)\\
& = f_{x}(a)\end{align}$

(The limits go to zero since $u$ and $v$ are continuous, from the continuity of $f$ )

Then,

$\begin{align} \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(a+z)-f(a)-zf_{x}(a)}{z} = 0\end{align}$

It implies that $f$ is complex differentiable at $a$.

Hence $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{U}$

Have I made any conceptual errors?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: your error is that you assume that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}h(x,y)$ can be done successively, in other words first doing the limit with $y \to 0$ and then with $x \to 0$ or vice versa; looking at a simple function like $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}$ for which the limit doesn't exists but the successive limits exist and are different should give an idea why things can go wrong; Looman-Menchoff is quite a difficult theorem with a subtle proof that depends on Baire lemma and some measure-theoretic results and requires the full content of the hypothesis

Comment: You don't need matrices and operators to show $f$ holomorphic. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations in detail.

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for your reply Sir. Can't we do the limits successively if the function is continuous? Pardon me if I asked something silly.

Comment: The problem there is that you do a ratio of continuous functions that both go to zero like in the $x^2/(x^2+y^2)$ case